# The name of a person who controls a bridge?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, professions

If I say:

> He was a bridgetender for some years.

How would I translate that into French?

Comment: Attention à ne pas utiliser le faux-ami *officier de pont* (une fonction dans la marine militaire), qui fait référence au pont d'un navire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only specific French word I can remember for this occupation/activity is **pontier**, but it's extremely rare (French definition [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pontier)). I think in most cases this would be described rather than named like that. A direct translation of your example could be simply:

> Il était pontier depuis des années.

but in some specific contexts it might as well be one of these periphrasis:

- Il travaillait sur un pont depuis des années.
- Il manœuvrait un pont depuis des années.
- Il était affecté à un pont depuis des années.
- Il travaillait à manoeuvrer un pont depuis des années.

Comment: « Il travaillait à manœuvrer un pont » does not sound like a job but rather like a task or a hobby.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez expensive hobby indeed ! Or else a task, but... over years ?! The context makes it clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

If I had to make myself clear about it, I'd use *gardien de pont* or *responsable de pont*, the former if it's not too incorect with regard to the real job, the latter to be less precise, and less natural, but easy to understand.

If it's meant to be litterary, [Romain's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2875/1514) is very good.

---

Si je devais le faire comprendre plutôt que de verser dans le style littéraire, je dirais quelque chose comme ***gardien de pont***, qui sonne pas mal, mais ne décrit pas forcément très bien l'activité, ou alors *responsable de pont*, plus vague, mais clair.

Comment: J'aime assez *gardien de pont*, qui ne laisse aucune ambiguité me semble-t-il. En revanche, le pontier est plus un agent qu'un responsable, donc *responsable de pont* pourrait (selon le contexte) ne pas convenir.

Comment: @RomainVALERI C'est-à-dire que *responsable d'activité de pont* sonne moins bien, d'un coup ; mais dans mon idée, *responsable de pont* couvre très large, et peut englober beaucoup de choses. *Agent de pont* alors, éventuellement.